# Embed live tv channel from website into my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to embed a live tv channel from their website into my website. But unable to do that. The channel is live at http://live.arynews.tv/

I tried

```
<embed src="http://www.live.arynews.tv" width="550px" height="500px">
```

but couldn't succeed. Please guide me how can i setup this particular chaneel and if i want to embed any other channel what is the procedure.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to embed an entire *website*, rather than using a [HTML5 `<video>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) element, [Java applet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet#Embedding_into_a_web_page), or [Flash SWF](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html) file. You *could* display the whole site in an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Fiframe), but I doubt that this is what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The embed tag is only for media files, not for entire websites. You probably want to use an iframe instead. For example:

```
<iframe src="http://live.arynews.tv" width="550px" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Comment: can u please guide me

Comment: I added another website to show it works. I don't have access to the website in your post

Comment: @JacodeGroot That's because the URL in the question is wrong; it should be http://live.arynews.tv/ (I've edited the post to correct this, but it is still awaiting review).

Comment: @JacodeGroot <iframe src="http://live.arynews.tv/" width="550px" height="500px"></iframe> this embed the whole website not the player. i want just to show the player. thansk

Comment: Do their terms and conditions allow you to just embed the player ?